# JQuery Validation not triggering

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, validation

I've made some kind of a *faux pas* in my programming logic. Please evaluate the following:

```
<form id="LeadForm" method="post" action="">
  <div id="lead_form_step_1">
  <asp:Label ID="lblProgramOfInterest" class="lead_form" runat="server" Text="Program of Interest"></asp:Label><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProgramOfInterest" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
  <p />

  <span class="next">Next &gt;&gt;</span>
  </div>

  <div id="lead_form_step_2">
  <div class="lead_form">First Name:<input type="text" id="NameFirst" class="required" minlength="2"/></div>
  <div class="lead_form">Last Name:<input type="text" id="NameLast" /></div>
  <div class="lead_form">Address:<input type="text" id="AddressLine1" /></div>
  <div class="lead_form">Address:<input type="text" id="AddressLine2" /></div>
  <div class="lead_form">City:<input type="text" id="AddressCity" /></div>
  <div class="lead_form">State:<input type="text" id="AddressState" /></div>
  <div class="lead_form">Zip Code:<input type="text" id="AddressZip" /></div>
   <p />
  <span class="prev">&lt;&lt; Previous</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="next">Next &gt;&gt;</span>
  </div>

  <div id="lead_form_step_3">
  <div class="lead_form">Email:<input type="text" id="EmailAddress" /></div>
  <div class="lead_form">Phone:<input type="text" id="HomePhone" /></div>
  <div class="lead_form">Mobile:<input type="text" id="MobilePhone" /></div>
  <div class="lead_form">Inquired Before:<input type="checkbox" id="InquiredBefore" /></div>
  <br /><span class="prev">&lt;&lt; Previous</span> &nbsp;<span class="leadsubmit">Submit</span>

 </div>
 </form>
```

The following is the JQuery validator and div-switcher:

```
$('#lead_form_step_2 .prev').click(function (event) {
    $('#LeadForm').validate();
    $('#lead_form_step_2').hide();
    $('#lead_form_step_1').show();
});

$('#lead_form_step_2 .next').click(function (event) {
    $('#LeadForm').validate()
    $('#lead_form_step_2').hide();
    $('#lead_form_step_3').show();
});
```

What i'm unsure of here, is that the validate() method is not stopping the progression of the form when I click on the next/prev links. Matter of fact its not validating at all. I'm utilizing [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation#A_few_things_to_look_for_when_playing_around_with_the_demo) tutorial, What have I missed?

Comment: I found that my validation was not working unless I added the "name" attribute to the fields.

Comment: Interesting, what jquery validator plugin were you using?

Comment: I was using a jquery implementation which came with one of the ASP.NET MVC 3 templates. (jquery-1.5.1). I was using the custom validator code in JS, not just letting jquery determine the validation rules based on CSS classes. *shrug* this is the first time I am using it, so perhaps there was some other factor which I overlooked.

Comment: The library i used seems to have been a fairly popular one http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/  I've since rolled my own and use it on a per-instance basis as its a collection of about 50 regex's and i can map them as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is wrap your `$('#LeadForm').validate()` in a conditional statement and return true if it validates and false otherwise. Your .next click event could be altered like so

```
$('#lead_form_step_2 .next').click(function (event) {
 if($('#LeadForm').validate())
 {
 $('#lead_form_step_2').hide();
 $('#lead_form_step_3').show();
 }
 else return false;
});
```

Comment: Its still not triggering on blank input of the NameFirst field. or at all for that matter. setting a breakpoint in the JS did not fire.

Comment: Is a reference to the validate plugin included in your aspx file

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="/JavaScript/JQuery/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
Sure is, and its showing as loaded 200 OK in the Net panel of firebug

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason that it is stopping is because the .validate() function has a return which is stopping the progression. Perhaps it would be better to perform the validation when you're submitting the form or on blur/change for each of the input elements like so?

$('input,select').blur(function {
    $('#LeadForm').validate();
});

This way after each element is changed or unselected you are validating the form again?

Hope this helps!

**validate( [options] )**

> This method sets up event handlers for **submit, focus, keyup, blur and click** to trigger validation of the entire form or individual elements. Each one can be disabled, see the onxxx options (onsubmit, onfocusout, onkeyup, onclick). focusInvalid focuses elements when submitting a invalid form.

Answer (score 0):

in my case there are multiple forms in current page, and I am using :

```
$('form').validate()
```

which makes jQuery.validate confused.

solution:  assign a specify ID selector for your form.  e.g.

```
$('#my_form_id').validate()
```